# Wordpress refresh table after insert new data

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, wordpress, refresh

I really don't have any idea with this problem. I create new plug-in. Structure is easy:
div FreeQuotation_wrap2 (display the table), div FreeQuotation_wrap3 (insert new data). But after write new data and click submit page is refresh with old data.

When I click refresh I see information that it will resend data to database. It's ok- I prevent it with unique. Now I see new table with new record. How can I make it automatically?

I try 3 methods: onSubmit="" (doesn't work) and javascript (window.location = "...") and trick with session (i get error - headers already sent by...).

```
<?php
global $FreeQuotation_version;
global $wpdb;
echo $table_name;
global $today_date;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'free_quotation_kic';

?>
<div class="FreeQuotation_wrap">
    <h2><div class="FreeQuotation_header"></div> FreeQuotation <?php echo $FreeQuotation_version; ?></h2><br>

</div>
<div class="FreeQuotation_wrap2">
    <table class="widefat">
        <?php 
        $FreeQuotation_table = $wpdb->get_results(
        "
        SELECT *
        FROM $table_name
        ORDER BY adding_date DESC
        LIMIT 0 , 10
        "
        ); 
        //nagłówek
            echo '<thead><tr><th> ID </th><th> Quotation </th><th> Author </th><th> Display Date </th><th> Delete </th></tr></thead>';
        //treść
        foreach ( $FreeQuotation_table as $ogresults ) 
        {
            echo '<tr><td>'; 
            echo $ogresults->id; 
            echo '</td><td>'; 
            echo $ogresults->quotation; 
            echo '</td><td>'; 
            echo $ogresults->author;
            echo '</td><td>';
            echo $ogresults->display_date;
                echo '</td></tr>'; 
        }
        echo '<tfoot><tr><th> ID </td><th> Quotation </td><th> Author </td><th> Display Date </th><th> Delete </td></tr></tfoot>';
        ?>
    </table>
</div>
<div class= "FreeQuotation_wrap3">
    <form method="post" action="options.php">
        <?php settings_fields('FreeQuotation_settings_filed'); ?>
        <?php $options = get_option('FreeQuotation_options'); ?>
    </form>
<?php

    global $current_user;
    $ufUserID = $current_user->ID;
    $quotation = $_POST["quotation_textarea"];
    $author = $_POST["autor_text"];
    $display_date = $_POST["display_date"];
    $url = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    $adding_date = $today_date;
    echo $url;
    if ( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) && $_POST['action'] == 'updateFeedback' ) {
        $FreeQuotation = $wpdb->insert( 'wp_free_quotation_kic', array( 'quotation' => $quotation, 'author' => $author, 'display_date' => $display_date, 'adding_date' => $adding_date,) );
    }?>

    <a href="<?php echo $url;?>">TUTAJ</a>
    <h3 class="widget-title">Add quotation</h3>
    <form id='reloader' method='post' onSubmit="<?php echo $url;?>">
        <table class="widefat" >
            <thead>
            <tr><th>Quotation</th><th>Author</th><th>Display Date</th></tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr><td>
            <textarea rows="1" cols="100" name="quotation_textarea" required></textarea>
            </td>
            <td>
            <input type="text" name="autor_text" required></input>
            </td>
            <td>
            <input type="text" name="display_date" required></input>
            </td></th>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
            <tr><th>
            <input class="button button-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
            <?php wp_nonce_field( 'updateFeedback' ); ?>
            <input name="action" type="hidden" id="action" value="updateFeedback"/>
            </th></td>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </form><br>
</div>
<div class="FreeQuotation_wrap4">
    <h3>Zmiany:</h3>

</div>
<?php 
?>
```

Can you help me? It's my first question hire (and I believe that the last...). Usually when I try to write a question I find the answer quickly :) Now I spend few hours with this problem and I doesn't see any solution...

Comment: Once again: *Do not use custom tables in WordPress if you can easily avoid them* [Here's why and how to avoid it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20056441/developing-a-wordpress-plugin-seo-friendly/20056568#20056568) It will give you all sorts of cool benefits. Like `WP_Query`, tagging, categories, slugs...

Comment: I know WP_Query and so on and I use it when I can. I need use custom table in other situation and this is why I try use it in this plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find simple solution - it's very easy and it's work. Maybe it's not professional but I don't have any other idea...

I change the order on the page. First is the form to add new position, the second is now the table with output. It means that I change two  order:

```
<div class= "FreeQuotation_wrap3">
...
</div>

<div class="FreeQuotation_wrap2">
...
</div>
```

And this is my first answer on stackoverflow.com ;-)